# Syntax Error in JFrame Connected to Database

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

I am an amateur high school programmer building a Java program using the `NetBeans IDE`. The program itself is quite simple: a `JFrame` that opens into two separate ones (`addMedicine` and `takeMedicine`). The `addMedicine` frame is connected to a database on NetBeans, but whenever I compile, the main frame that leads into the two others comes up, but once `addMedicine` is clicked on from the main frame, I get this:

```
Syntax error: Encountered "Add" at line 1, column 15.
```

I checked my program at line 1 and column 15 but found nothing that had the word "Add". Please check my source code to identify any errors.

```
package my.addMedicine;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class addMedicine extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    Connection con;
    Statement stmt;
    ResultSet rs;


public addMedicine()
{
    initComponents();
    DoConnect();
}

private void DoConnect(){
    try 
        {
            String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Add Medicine";
            String uName = "apandia";
            String uPass = "olympics2012";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);

            stmt = con.createStatement();
            String SQL = "SELECT * FROM Add Medicine";
            rs = stmt.executeQuery (SQL);

            rs.next();

            String NAMEMEDICINE = rs.getString("NAMEMEDICINE");
            int MGDOSAGE_col = rs.getInt("MGDOSAGE");
            String MGDOSAGE = Integer.toString( MGDOSAGE_col );
            String DAYS = rs.getString("DAYS");
            int NUMBERTIMES_col = rs.getInt("NUMBERTIMES");
            String NUMBERTIMES = Integer.toString( NUMBERTIMES_col );

            textNAMEMEDICINE.setText(NAMEMEDICINE);
            textDose.setText(MGDOSAGE);
            textDAYS.setText(DAYS);
            textNUMBERTIMES.setText(NUMBERTIMES);

        }
    catch (SQLException err)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, err.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: I would guess that it's complaining about your SQL statement. The word Add is in the 15th position. That SQL doesn't look correct to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Add Medicine
123456789012345 <- column 15!
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for your help. I had the incorrect table in `SELECT*FROM Add Medicine`. I was supposed to use TABLEMEDICINES, and that fixed the error!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `while` loop instead of only `rs.next();` like this:

```
 while(rs.next()){
  your code
  ...
```

Or just use `if` statement:

```
 if(rs.next()){
 your code
 ...
```